# Alternative to dataframe .head(), trying to print a sorted dictionary based on value and only return top specified results

Tags: python

I have a script that scans a folder for all file extensions and returns them in a dataframe that's sorted largest to smallest

```
>> myscript.py --top 3

 ext    count
.py     20
.txt    15
.xls    5
```

But for the sake of speed I don't want to use a dataframe, but instead use the dictionary it's built from as it's much faster. Is it possible to sort a dictionary and let the user get a certain amount of values back?

My script is on par with a bash script in terms of speed, but it's even faster if I don't use Pandas! The actual importing of pandas slows the script :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sort a `dict` with `sorted`, but you won't get a `dict` back without explicit conversion, because `dicts` are inherently unordered (save that they *will probably* respect insertion order in Python 3.6, and *must* in Python >= 3.7).

Example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'.xls': 5,
     '.py': 20,
     '.txt': 15}

result = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

print(result)
print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
[('.xls', 5), ('.txt', 15), ('.py', 20)]
{'.xls': 5, '.txt': 15, '.py': 20}
```

If you want, say the top 2 values, just perform slicing:

```
print(result[:2])
print(dict(result[:2]))
```

Output:

```
[('.py', 20), ('.txt', 15)]
{'.py': 20, '.txt': 15}
```

You can also change the sort order by passing `reversed=True`.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to [gmds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11015427/gmds) answer, I was able to create a similar look to a dataframe doing the following:

```
result = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for item in result[:self.top]:
    # How wide I want my spacing
    total_space = 50

    # the length of the key
    x_space = len(item[0])

    # the length of the value, string first so I can count how many digits
    y_space = len(str(item[1]))

    # The space left over
    remaining_space = total_space - x_space - y_space

    # the character to fill the space, could use - or . or _
    gap = ' ' * remaining_space
    print(f'{item[0]}{gap}{item[1]}')

    # Output

.py                                              2
.csv                                             1
```

Before it would print unevenly spaced. An alternative to manually setting the total space would be to find the key with longest character length and basing it off of that.

Comment: You can use `pprint` for that.

Comment: Couldnt get it to do it it was just print like a dictionary